# Is it possible to navigate from webbrowser NavigationFailed event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
private void webBrowser_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Failed");

        if (!Utils.IsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Please go to Settings and enable your network connection.",
                                                 "No network connection", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {                    
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TutorialPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))); //TODO: Doesnt work
            }
        }
}
```

Is this posible? i want go to previous xaml page not webpage.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or it just doesn't work?

Comment: Just doesnt work. Doesnt make the navigation

Comment: Does the failed event args have an e.Handled property you can set to true? Try that.

Comment: OK I see you mentioned that didn't work. Sorry about that. If you put a breakpoint in the webBrowser_NavigationFailed method, does it get hit?

Comment: Yes it does it comes to this   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TutorialPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative))); and does that also

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with another thing you can try.

Comment: Never mind, that doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: thanks for help i hope someone will know :D

Comment: How does one even simulate a NavigationFailed? I am trying to get one so I can give this a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and it runs ok. [Here is my simple example](http://1drv.ms/1jV4l4h). You can Navigate in NavigationFailedEvent - the problem is that you never get there.

As I've tried the problem mostly concerns Emulator - probably due to how internet connection is realized. For example:

```
web.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://nosite.azd", UriKind.Absolute));
```

this Navigation hadn't failed on my Emulator (I was redirected somewhere), but as I've tested it on the Device - it failed.

So try to test your App on device. But IMO it will be much better to check for the internet connection before Navigating (Loading Webbrowser) rather that waiting Navigation to Fail (it can be an additional check up).

Also you don't need to Navigate via Dispatcher as your code runs on main thread.

Comment: Looking at your code to simulate a failure, I was also able to verify that navigation in the NavigationFailed handler works just fine.

Comment: @EricScherrer It took me a little while to simulate the fail on emulator ;) Even airplane mode hadn't helped.

Comment: i did it before navigation